# ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows ORA-06512: at line 5

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, procedural-programming

```
   set serveroutput on;  
   set verify off;  
   set autoprint on;  
   variable b_employee_id employees.employee_id%type;  
declare  
   v_last_name employees.last_name%type;  
   v_emp_id employees.employee_id%type;   
   begin  
   select employee_id into :b_employee_id from employees   
   where last_name='&v_last_name';   

  end;  
/
```

Answer (score 3):

The error message is self explanatory. Your `select` statement returned more than one row.  When you use the `INTO` clause the select cannot return more than one row.

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems045.htm):

> By default, a **SELECT INTO statement must return only one row**.
>   Otherwise, PL/SQL raises the predefined exception TOO_MANY_ROWS and
>   the values of the variables in the INTO clause are undefined. Make
>   sure your WHERE clause is specific enough to only match one row
>
> If no rows are returned, PL/SQL raises NO_DATA_FOUND. You can guard
>   against this exception by selecting the result of an aggregate
>   function, such as COUNT(*) or AVG(), where practical. These functions
>   are guaranteed to return a single value, even if no rows match the
>   condition.

Answer (score 0):

**exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows**

This means, there are **more than one entry** in the database for given `last_name`.

If you want, you can get **max** `employee_id` for given `last_name` as below.

```
select max(employee_id) into :b_employee_id from employees   
   where last_name='&v_last_name';
```